# how to convert tihs sql query to entity framework lambda expression?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

how do i convert the following sql query to entity framework lambda expression ?

```
SELECT MAX(StudentID) FROM students GROUP BY CountryID, CityID
```

Comment: Odd query. No need to select CountryID and CityID?

Comment: @jarlh this query is not original but it is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The following lambda expression can be used as an equivalent of above SQL

```
db.students.GroupBy(a => new { a.CityID, a.CountryID })
.Select(a => new { a.Key, StudentID = a.Max(b => b.StudentID) })
.Select(a=> a.StudentID).ToList();
```

**Explanation:** First, list is grouped by CityID and CountryID. Second, the grouped columns and Max of StudentID is selected. Third, only StudentID is picked and converted into a list.